# Disable and uncheck checkboxes in table with And Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

### Issues and what I tried

I'm using Ant Design Table and CheckBox for frontend development.

I am newbie for frontend fields.

Here is my implementation to uncheck and disable all checkboxes in table with disable button.

I could somehow implement disable functionality but checkboxes cannot be checked by this approach.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Checkbox, Button } from 'antd';

const data = [
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 30,
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 25,
    disabled: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Peter Smith',
    age: 40,
    disabled: false,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [disableAll, setDisableAll] = useState(false);

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const toggleDisable = () => {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
    setChecked(false);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setDisableAll(e.target.checked);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Disable',
      dataIndex: 'disabled',
      render: (_, dataIndex) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={checked}
          disabled={disabled}
          onChange={onChange}
        ></Checkbox>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        style={{ margin: '0 10px' }}
        type="primary"
        size="small"
        onClick={toggleDisable}
      >
        {!disabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable'}
      </Button>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} rowKey="name" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Expected behaviour

0. initial state
   [image]
1. check checkboxes
   [image]
2. uncheck and disable checkboxes
   [image]

Comment: Try this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-fbwgn8?file=package.json,src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a **key** property for each data item, which is used as the **rowKey** for the Table. It also manages the **checked** and disabled states within each data item, allowing for individual control over each checkbox. The **toggleDisable** function now toggles the disabled state and unchecks the checkboxes if they are being disabled. The **onChange** function is updated to handle checkbox changes individually.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Checkbox, Button } from 'antd';

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 30,
    disabled: false,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 25,
    disabled: false,
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Peter Smith',
    age: 40,
    disabled: false,
    checked: false,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState(data);

  const toggleDisable = () => {
    const newData = dataSource.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      disabled: !item.disabled,
      checked: item.disabled ? item.checked : false,
    }));
    setDataSource(newData);
  };

  const onChange = (record, e) => {
    const newData = dataSource.map(item => {
      if (item.key === record.key) {
        return { ...item, checked: e.target.checked };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setDataSource(newData);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Disable',
      dataIndex: '',
      render: (text, record) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={record.checked}
          disabled={record.disabled}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(record, e)}
        />
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        style={{ margin: '0 10px' }}
        type="primary"
        size="small"
        onClick={toggleDisable}
      >
        {dataSource.some(item => item.disabled) ? 'Enable' : 'Disable'} All
      </Button>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} rowKey="key" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```